# Optimize JOIN for a large dataset in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization

I need to create a table with the running total (aka cumulative sum) per client per day from a large dataset (200 GB). However, my current code is too slow: it has been running for days and still has not finished.

My data came from two tables. The table Orders informs the order id and client id. The table Transactions informs the order id, date and status (status=5 means order approved, status=7 means order rejected).

```
CREATE TABLE RunningTotal AS
    SELECT DISTINCT Orders.ClientId,
        Transactions.Date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Transactions.Status = 5 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Orders.ClientId ORDER BY Transactions.Date) AS RunTotal
    FROM Transactions
    LEFT JOIN Orders ON Transactions.Order_Id= Orders.Id
    WHERE Transactions.Status IN (5,7)
```

I used a toy table to test and my current code provides the expected results: the net running total of approved order per client per day. The problem seems to be how to optimize it to use with a large dataset. I might be wrong, but I believe my bottleneck is the **JOIN**. If I run a similar query with just one table, it takes minutes.

The command EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN gives​ me the following:

> CO-ROUTINE 3
>
> SEARCH TABLE Transactions USING INDEX idx_trans_status (Status=?)
>
> SEARCH TABLE Orders USING INDEX idx_orders_id (Id=?)
>
> USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
>
> SCAN SUBQUERY 3
>
> USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
>
> USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY

EDIT:

The output table would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions (
  ClientId  INTEGER,
  Date   DATE,
  RunTotal  INTEGER
  PRIMARY KEY (ClientId, Date)
)

ClientId     Date    RunTotal
-------- ----------- --------
1        2018-12-28  110
1        2018-12-30  125
3        2018-10-15  87
3        2018-11-22  93
3        2018-11-24  99
```

'Orders' table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
  Id  INTEGER,
  ClientId   INTEGER
  Class  INTEGER,
  Recall  INTEGER,
  Family  INTEGER,
  CreationDate  DATE,
  DeletionDate  DATE,
  Level  INTEGER,
  Notes  TEXT,
  Tags  TEXT,
  Operator_ID INTEGER,
  Node  INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

'Transactions' table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions (
  Id INTEGER,
  Order_Id  INTEGER,
  Date   DATE,
  Status   INTEGER,
  Amount INTEGER,
  Operator_ID INTEGER,
  Notes  TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of the `explain query plan` output?

Comment: @RomanKonoval Sorry for that, it's my first question here. I think now I fixed that.

Comment: Joining a subquery that just selects from a table instead of just joining on the table in question is odd looking. You can leave out the `ORDER BY` since you're inserting the resulting rows into a table. Do you really want/need that `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Also run  `ANALYZE` if you haven't already. And maybe use a covering index on the transactions table.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for the comment. Regarding the subquery and the `ORDER BY` issues, you are right, I will fix that. Regarding the `DISTINCT`, I really need it, otherwise, the code returns repeated times the running total for each day. For example, if client A had 5 transactions on a given day, the code without that `DISTINCT` returns 5 lines with the same day, client and running total.

Comment: @Shawn beyond the indexes displayed at the query plan, I have a covering index on transactions (Date, Status), but it seems that this covering index does not help sqlite. Was that covering index what you had in mind?

Comment: Ack, missed a column. `transactions(status, order_id, date)`. Or maybe `transactions(order_id, status, date)`. Not sure which would be better; depends on the distribution of your data. And unless `orders.id` is an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, `orders(id, clientid)`.

Comment: @Shawn thanks for the idea, but these new covering indexes also didn't work.

Comment: Could you post your full table definitions? Also, the SQLITE_STAT table contents; that is, the output of `SELECT * FROM sqlite_stat1`, `SELECT * FROM sqlite_stat3`, and `SELECT * FROM sqlite_stat4` (stat4 may not exist; that's fine). That way, we should be able to reproduce your query plans locally, even without the actual data. Your exact sqlite version may also be important.

Comment: @SnildDolkow I think now I added the information you required. If not, please let me know =)

Comment: I'd like the SQLITE_STAT table data, too. Also, is there a `client` table or similar, with unique client ID:s? It might be useful. Finally, are you sure those are the full table definitions? They look really sparse (not much info), and don't even have primary keys...

Comment: @SnildDolkow I added more info, I am sorry, this is my first question here – I was afraid the question would become too long. Regarding the `client` table, I have one but contains only client registration information. My guess is that the JOIN is my bottleneck.

Comment: Regarding the `client` table: if it has a primary key on the client ID, it's a fast way to get a list of uniqie client IDs. That's why I'm interested in it. And I'd still like to see that SQLITE_STAT table content. :)

Comment: @SnildDolkow I am so sorry, I realized just now what is a sqlite_stat! As soon as get to the office, I can add it. Regarding the `client` table, yes, it has a primary key on the client ID! =) What is your idea?

Comment: Not sure yet. Maybe flipping inner and outer queries, trying `COUNT() - COUNT()` instead of `SUM(CASE..)`, and definitely more indices. Let's see where some experiments take us. :)